# ClickOnce application creating a new firewall rule on every update

Tags: clickonce, windows-firewall

I have an application that uses TCP to allow for instant notification over our internal network and published it using [Visual Studio Professional 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012). I'm finding that on each update though (still using the auto updating feature provided by [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce)), it's adding in a new firewall rule, because it's installed in a slightly different folder (for example, C:\users\username\appdata\local\apps\2.0\vhhecqeo.hox\eqaz9px7.kdb\mant..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0002_ebb40fc614f8be21\mantra.exe
is this next time:
C:\users\trent.jones\appdata\local\apps\2.0\vhhecqeo.hox\eqaz9px7.kdb\mant..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0002_ae7718736748fac0\mantra.exe).

Marginally different, but ClickOnce doesn't allow me to specify an install folder (due 
to [how ClickOnce files work](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/175497/How-to-specify-the-Installation-folder-to-C-progra).

I could use `netsh` to add in/check for the rules manually, but that's horrible because I would still need to run it as administrator/local administrator and most users aren't. Plus, I'm not sure that would stop Windows firewall checking/adding its own version of the rule..

Is there another way of fixing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClickOnce applications and Windows Firewall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818034/clickonce-applications-and-windows-firewall)

Comment: It seems nobody has a reasonable solution to this problem short of disabling Windows Firewall.